# iCloud Drive take forever to upload. Is there a way to rush "Waiting to upload state"?

Tags: swift, uikit, icloud, nsfilemanager, icloud-drive

I have two 50KB files saved in iCloud Drive. Using FileManager, saved in an iCloud container.

The problem is that they take forever to upload. I waited 2 hours and they are still in this waiting to upload status. Both my iPhone and iPad having this issue.

Is there a way I can force it upload? Or at least put it into priority queue.

I'm building a note app sync feature. And those slow upload makes sync impossible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a problem like yours and tried to find the solution. So, I contacted directly to Apple Support.
Here's the suggestion:

First, you have to make sure that your OS version is up to date and your iCloud storage has enough space.

Next, you go to System Preference > Apple ID > uncheck a checkbox in front of iCloud then check it back.